# Jena Eclipse Plugin running with Mars 4.5

Tags: eclipse, jena

I have come across the [Jena 2.0 Library Plugin](http://owl-eclipse.projects.semwebcentral.org/Jena/), an Eclipse Plugin found at [SemWebCentral](http://projects.semwebcentral.org/projects/owl-eclipse/). I have tried to install it within Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers - Version: Mars Release (4.5.0), but I am returned with the following error:

" An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.daml.jena 1.0.0, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]org.daml.jena 1.0.0."

The plugin is most probably outdated considering the version of Eclipse I am using and I have been struggling to find info on compatible versions. Has anybody stumbled across the same issue?

Thank you very much,

I.

Comment: On the man [BBN Technologies](http://owl-eclipse.projects.semwebcentral.org/) page, Eclipse 3.1 is listed as the required Eclipse.  Yes, the plug-in is probably outdated..

Comment: FYI Jena recently released Version 3.0 so a Jena 2.0 plugin will be woefully out of date given that the final 2.x version was 2.13.0

Comment: Thank you both, it is a pity that this plug-in has been abandoned.